# Best lens for landscape photography on a crop-sensor body (APS-C)

Tags: lens, landscape, cropped-sensor

Recently I've been studying Elia Locardi's work and I've noticed he shoots on a Nikon D810 (full frame) with a 14-24mm lens. Even though 14mm is really wide especially on a full frame body, it doesn't seem too wide (like a fisheye).
As a Canon 750D owner I was wondering, is there some kind of lens out there which gives you high quality shots and doesn't distort like crazy (and doesn't cost a kidney - I'm looking at you Canon L lens)? Where is that edge of where it becomes more of a fisheye? I've googled on this but there was nothing specifically to find about apsc in this context and I can imagine there is no right or wrong answer here, like most of the times. But I am curious as to what you think about this.

Cheers

Edit: I'm aiming for good wide angle lenses. I have a sigma 16-50 f2.8 on my apsc body, but I feel like I still could make a step up from there in terms of quality and possible a little wider as well. Just not fisheye, that doesn't really float my boat

Comment: 'Best' is always going to be subjective - some people take really good landscapes with a telephoto. Perhaps 'lens type recommendation in order to emulate the style of xyz on an APS?'

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I completely agree. I'll edit that in

Comment: The word you're looking for, btw, is *rectilinear* - Not a recommendation [& can't be an answer] but Google turned up the [Laowa 12mm f/2.8](http://www.venuslens.net/product/laowa-12mm-f2-8-zero-d/) & this [PetaPixel review](https://petapixel.com/2016/07/26/laowa-12mm-f2-8-widest-rectilinear-f2-8-lens/) ...though I've now got my eye on their 60mm 2:1 macro [never stop spending in this game ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin ah yea I forgot about that zero-D lens, but it as well is pretty pricey (not Canon L pricey though)

Comment: As @Tetsujin says, you should look up rectilinear lens vs fisheye lens. The focal length doesn't determine this.

Comment: Also [How wide can a lens be before it begins to produce distortion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/how-wide-can-a-lens-be-before-it-begins-to-produce-distortion)

Comment: Panoramas in post processing and large format film are alternative ways of creating wider and/or more detailed landscape images. The search for a new lens may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Related: [Does wide angle equivalent in crop sensor skew image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48337/15871), including the comments to [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/48342/15871)

Comment: Putting the camera system into title or tags would be useful.

Comment: Related: [Understanding Lens Viewing Angle and Focal Length Relationship](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92788/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fisheye lens is a fisheye lens. It is constructed that way. The opposite of that is a rectilinear lens and that is also constructed to be rectilinear.

The Nikkor 14-24mm F/2.8 is one of my all-time favorite lenses because it one of the widest rectilinear lenses with a constant aperture available. It was for a long time but there are other options now. On my site, you can easily search for such a lens. Here is a [link to all Canon EF-compatible full-frame rectilinear zoom lenses that go wider than 15mm](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=canon&crop=1%3Amax&focalwide=15%3Amax&zoom=1&rectilinear=1&by=feature). This is a live link, so more results will appear as new ones get announced.

The Canon offering is the EF 11-24mm F/4L. It is extremely wide and probably high quality but I have not tested it yet. The Sigma Art 12-24mm F/4 DG HSM is an excellent performer for roughly half the price of the Canon! It is very sharp and shows little distortion, although a fair amount of vignetting. The Tamron SP 15-30mm F/2.8 is one of their better lenses, although far from being as wide as the Canon and Sigma offerings.

At this point in time, APS-C cameras are at a disadvantage. There is no comparable rectilinear lens to the ones mentioned above. To get only a 15mm equivalent you need to have something that is wider than 10mm on an APS-C camera, even more so with Canon's 1.6X crop. Still here is a similar search for [Canon EF-mount APS-C rectilinear zoom lenses that are at least 10mm wide](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=canon&crop=1.6%3Amax&focalwide=10%3Amax&zoom=1&rectilinear=1&by=feature).

When you see Elia Locardi's images (I am also familiar with his work), the wide-angle is one thing that gives them the striking perspective. There is also a huge amount of processing but that has nothing to do with the lens. To get a similar perspective on an APS-C camera, the only choice is the Sigma 8-16mm F/4.5-5.6 DC HSM. Its quality is fairly good with excellent sharpness but it has strong barrel distortion (which is *not* the same as fisheye projection) and really heavy vignetting. It is a lens that I often considered but ended up deciding it is better to change sensor formats (Even [all 7-14mm lenses for Micro Four-Thirds](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=m43&focalwide=8%3Amax&zoom=1&rectilinear=1&by=feature) are much better performers). People do correct some distortion in software but beware that it always reduces image-quality and it will affect your framing, significantly so if there is a high amount of barrel distortion.

Comment: There is also a Sigma 10-20mm f3.5 for APS-C.

Comment: It is there in the search results, among several 10-Xmm ones, but it isn't much good. The difference in angle-of-view between 8mm and 10mm is significative too.